# Py4JJavaError: PythonRDD.collectAndServe when using action command in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark, spark

Estoy empezando con *Python Spark* intentando hacer este ejercicio en el que hay que calcular la media de amigos por edades de una red social. Este es el código que hice:

```
def preprocesamiento_datos(line):
    fds = line.split(',') 
    anios = int(fields[2]) 
    num_amigos= int(fields[3]) 
    
    return (anios, num_amigos) 

lines = sc.textFile("text_triying_4.txt")
rdd = lines.map(preprocesamiento_datos) #Me preocupa la eficiencia aquí...
    
totalesPorEdad = rdd.mapValues(lambda x : (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y : (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]))


mediasPorEdad = totalesPorEdad.mapValues(lambda x : x[0] / x[1])


resultados = mediasPorEdad.collect()

for resultado in resultados:
    print(resultado)
```

El RDD se crea sin problemas, o al menos eso creo, porque si ejecuto todo el código de arriba excepto las 3 últimas líneas (desde `resultados`), y escribo mediasPorEdad esto devuelve algo tipo `PythonRDD[125] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53`. Tampoco es un error en los datos porque es un archivo `.txt` de este formato muy simple:

```
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 2
```

y solo son unas pocas líneas, para verificar el código. El archivo `text_triying_4.txt` está en la ubicación correcta.

Tampoco es problema de la instalación, pues estoy utilizando google collab porque no conseguí instalar Spark habiendo intentado muchas vías diferentes de instalación y encontrarme con una gran variedad de errores, por lo que decidí utilizar por el momento google collab y el `SparkContext()` se inicia correctamente. Este es el contexto de Spark:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("triying")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

Pero, cuando intento ejecutar acciones como collect() o take() en el código de arriba del todo, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 21.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 11)
```

Pero si utilio estas acciones en un `iterable` o `collection` como `sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).take(7)` o `sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).collect()`, funciona bien...

¡Cualquier tipo de ayuda será bienvenida!